# Get exchange volume or even price in a private network

Tags: web3js, ether

I am creating a local private network for some testing purpose,

just tested with sendTransaction and some others API.

Now, i would like to trace the private network exchange volume, and also price if possible.

The only answer i found are just API from worldwide API website, not private, is there a way to implement this in a private network?

Comment: The price is calculated by `market_cap / total_supply`.
Example of Ethereum; `30,759,612,210 / 94,459,239 = 325.6390008604664`
Since it's a private network, you'd know the market cap (since you'd be the exchange) and you'd also know the number of coins minted, *I think*.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are thinking this a bit wrong. If you have a private network with private Ether it's most likely not tradeable anywhere outside the blockchain. So there is no "exchange volume" or "price".

*Price* of Ether is something that is simply a matter of supply and demand. There is no central authority who decides on the price. If people want to buy it (from exchanges) the price goes up and vice-versa. So if there is no way for externals to buy your private Ether the Ether has no price (some might say it's worthless). With the same logic there is also no exchange volume.

Answer (score 1):

A way is to download any webpage giving the data you want (e.g. etherscan.io).
E.g. on linux:

```
 wget etherscan.io
 grep "@" index.html
```

Should give you the line containing the price of the ether in USD.
Then you have to write a script to clean it and get the price.
If you do not need it each second, it can be fine.

Else, an exchange could probably send those data to you in a more professional way, but I guess you would have to pay. If you are ready for it, perhaps you should contact them. Those exchanges are the markets were the price is established, so any other data are second-hand.

Comment: i am not connecting to outside with my private network, i have to create a local system use among a small group of ppl trading the eth with each other, and i have to record the transaction volume and the price they traded.

Comment: So you want to get outside information without connecting to the outside.. *bemused*

Comment: @PSo : be precise. What you call ETH is it actual external ETH or the local currency linked to your private blockchain? In the first case it is impossible without connecting to the internet.